# how get selected child index in QTreeWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtreewidget

How can I get the index of the selected child in such a hierarchical structure? By selecting item with name "child A", get its index.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = 0
    if QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication.instance()
    else:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    l1 = QTreeWidgetItem(["String A"])
    l2 = QTreeWidgetItem(["String AA"])
    l1_child = QTreeWidgetItem(["Child A"])
    l1.addChild(l1_child)
    l2_child = QTreeWidgetItem(["Child AA"])
    l2.addChild(l2_child)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(510, 210)

    tw = QTreeWidget(w)
    tw.resize(500, 200)
    tw.setColumnCount(1)
    tw.setHeaderHidden(True)
    tw.addTopLevelItem(l1)
    tw.addTopLevelItem(l2)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems confusing but I am going to analyze it literally.

There is no difference between a selected item that is a child or not of another item, if you want to obtain the selected item then you have the following options:

```py
# ...
w.show()

def on_itemSelectionChanged():
    items = tw.selectedItems()
    for it in items:
        print(it.text(0))

tw.itemSelectionChanged.connect(on_itemSelectionChanged)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```py
# ...
w.show()

def on_selectionChanged():
    indexes = tw.selectedIndexes()
    for index in indexes:
        print(index.data())

tw.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(on_selectionChanged)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to show the corresponding widget from the stack by the selected tree element (by its index). How do I get a specific index?

Comment: @user12589893 What do you mean by index? For example, what are the indexes of "Child A", "Child AA", "String A" and "String AA"?

Comment: @user12589893 some feedback?

Comment: I don't know, maybe a composite [parent, child]. I need to organize the movement between the tree elements and show a specific widget depending on it. So I need a unified identifier for each tree element. That's the point